# Missing name, in state: START_OBJECT parsing XML using Jackson

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I'm trying to parse some XML that looks like this:

```
<correlationMatrix>
    <assetMatrix numAssets="45">
        <correlations asset="Name1" />
        <correlations asset="Name2">
            <correlation asset="Name3">1.23</correlation>
        </correlations>
        <correlations asset="Name4">
            <correlation asset="Name5">2.34</correlation>
            <correlation asset="Name6">3.45</correlation>
        </correlations>
    </assetMatrix>
</correlationMatrix>
```

I've created 3 classes:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class CorrelationMatrix {
  private List<Correlations> assetMatrix;

  public List<Correlations> getAssetMatrix() {
    return assetMatrix;
  }

  public void setAssetMatrix(List<Correlations> assetMatrix) {
    this.assetMatrix = assetMatrix;
  }
}
```

And

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Correlations {
 private String asset;
 private List<Correlation> correlation;

 public String getAsset() {
   return asset;
 }

  public void setAsset(String asset) {
    this.asset = asset;
  }

  public List<Correlation> getCorrelation() {
    return correlation;
  }

  public void setCorrelations(List<Correlation> correlation) {
    this.correlation = correlation;
  }

}
```

Then finally

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Correlation {
}
```

As you can see I've removed everything from the final inner class, but it still fails to parse. I've tried removing `<correlations asset="Name1" />` from the input but that's not the source of the problem. If I remove `private List<Correlation> correlation;` from Correlations then that does then parse successfully but obviously doesn't have the information I need.

What is it that I need to do differently here to parse what is essentially a 2 dimensional array from XML into Java using Jackson (2.2.0 if that matters)?

The error I get is:

```
 Missing name, in state: START_OBJECT (through reference chain: CorrelationMatrix["assetMatrix"]->Correlations["correlation"])
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(
```

**Update:**

The problem seems to be associated with the values inside `correlation`. If I remove 1.23, 2.34 and 3.45 from my example data then it parses - so I need to somehow tell Jackson how to map them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to parse all the elements in the example xml with these modified classes (add getters, setters and use correct name `setCorrelation` in `Correlations`):

```
class CorrelationMatrix {
    private AssetMatrix assetMatrix;
}

class AssetMatrix {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private int numAssets;

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private List<Correlations> correlations;
}

class Correlations {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private String asset;

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private List<Correlation> correlation;
}

class Correlation {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private String asset;

    @JacksonXmlText
    private double correlation;
}
```

1. I didn't need `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` anywhere
2. `@JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)` is needed for attributes like `asset` and `numAssets`
3. There are 2 types of lists in the xml that are both unwrapped so specify it with this `@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)`
4. You can parse the innermost double numbers with this `@JacksonXmlText` although the field in Java is not text.
5. I introduced a wrapper class `AssetMatrix` to capture `numAssets`

Comment: Thanks a lot Manos, I'll try it out when I'm back at work tomorrow. (I cut down the XML for this example to try and focus on the root problem - the real XML has other attributes that I don't care about, hence the ignore)

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks again. I think the key missing component was the `@JacksonXmlText` annotation.